# what does this PHP regex pattern mean?

Tags: php, regex, string

Can anybody explain what does each character mean in this regex:

```
...preg_match('/\{loop(?: name){0,1}=\${0,1}(.*?)\}/', $html, $code)...
```

?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world for nice regex analyzation and debug tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like part of a template parser, perhaps.

```
\{loop(?: name){0,1}=\${0,1}(.*?)\}
--------------------
```

Matches `{loop name` or `{loop`. The `?:` tells the parser not to put that sub-pattern in the matches array. The `{0,1}` marks that it can appear zero or one time.

```
\{loop(?: name){0,1}=\${0,1}(.*?)\}
                    ---------------
```

Matches an equals sign, followed by an optional dollar sign (`$`), followed by some text, most likely the variable name, finishing off with a `}`

Instances of `{0,1}` could have been replaced with a `?`

Comment: thanks! What character makes the `$` optional? And which one would make it required?

Comment: oh nvm, you just said {0,1} does that :)

Answer (score 4):

Regex free-spacing 'x' mode comments to the rescue!

```
$re = '/
  \{         # Match a literal "{".
  loop       # Match the literal text: "loop".
  (?:        # Begin non-capture group to
    [ ]name  # match the literal text: " name"
  ){0,1}     # from zero to one times.
  =          # Match a literal "=".
  \${0,1}    # match literal "$" from zero to one times.
  (.*?)      # Capture in group $1 zero or more non-"\n".
  \}         # Match a literal "}".
  /x';
```

Comment: `[ ]` replaces the space character when you add `/x` ?

Comment: @Alex: Yes. In free-spacing mode, all whitespace is ignored unless it is escaped or inside a character class. i.e. instead of `"[ ]"`, I could have said: `"\ "` (which is less readable IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

`/` - Beginning of RegExp. 
`\{` - Matches a `{` character. => [`{`]
`loop` - Matches the word "loop" => [`{loop`]
`?:` - Don't include in matching array => [`{loop`]
`(`*`)` - Groups multiple tokens together. This allows you to apply quantifiers to the full group. This creates a capturing group.
`name` - Matches the word "name" => `{loop(name)`
`{0,1}` - Match the previous regex 0 to 1 time.
`=\$` - Matches "=$". => `{loop(name)=$`
`{0,1}` - Match the previous regex 0 to 1 time.
`(.*?)` - `.` = any word character. `*?` Matches 0 or more of the preceeding token. => `{loop(name)=$anything`
`\}` - Matches a `}` character. => `{loop(name)=$anything}`
 
`/` - End of RegExp.